# I cannot understand the role of index value inside the ngFor loop and how it helps in creating dynamic form fields

Tags: angular

I am trying to learn how to create dynamic form fields in angular, I am not able to comprehend the working logic of the index value inside the ngFor loop, and how this index value helps in creating the dynamic form field

product-form.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-form',
  templateUrl: './product-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-form.component.css']
})
export class ProductFormComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  productForm: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit() {

    /* Initiate the form structure */
    this.productForm = this.fb.group({
      title: [],
      selling_points: this.fb.array([this.fb.group({point:''})])
    })
  }

  get sellingPoints() {
    return this.productForm.get('selling_points') as FormArray;
  }

  /////// This is new /////////////////

  addSellingPoint() {
    this.sellingPoints.push(this.fb.group({point:''}));

  }

  deleteSellingPoint(index) {
    this.sellingPoints.removeAt(index);
  }

  //////////// End ////////////////////
}
```

product-form.component.html

```
<h1>Edit Product</h1>

<form [formGroup]="productForm">

  <label>
    Title: <input formControlName="title" />
  </label>
  <h2>Selling Points</h2>

  <div formArrayName="selling_points">
    <div *ngFor="let item of sellingPoints.controls; let pointIndex=index" [formGroupName]="pointIndex">
        {{pointIndex}} {{item}}
        <label>
      Selling Point: <input formControlName="point" />
    </label>
    <button type="button" (click)="deleteSellingPoint(pointIndex)">Delete Selling Point</button>
    </div>
    <button type="button" (click)="addSellingPoint()">Add Selling Point</button>
  </div>

</form>

{{ this.productForm.value | json }}
```

Comment: `pointIndex` is the numeric offset for each element in `ngFor`. What is confusing about that? Have you learned about for loops before? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop

Comment: with due respect sir! i have learned about for loops before, i do understand what you are saying, but, why do we have to assign the pointIndex to formGroupName

Comment: If you are creating multiple formGroup inside a form array, the name needs to be generated using the index. If you had a formArray that needed to contain multiple formControl then you would use the index in the formControlName field.

Comment: Sorry, but your question read as if you're asking how a loop works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form group is using an array. Which is declared here:

https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray

```js
selling_points: this.fb.array([this.fb.group({point:''})])
```

Form arrays are accessed via an *offset* numeric value.

https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray#at

The form group directive assigns the form group to the DOM element using an array offset.

https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroupName

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of sellingPoints.controls; let pointIndex=index" [formGroupName]="pointIndex">
```

Once a *group* is assigned to the DOM element. Controls can be used relative to that group.

```html
<input formControlName="point" />
```

The above references the form control within the current form group.

Your code also removes a form group by deleting the array item using the loop index value.

```js
deleteSellingPoint(index) {
    this.sellingPoints.removeAt(index);
  }
```

So if you call `this.sellingPoints.removeAt(0)` it will remove the first group.

Comment: Thank You sir! now i understood

Comment: @Nikshay if it answers your question, can you please accept and up vote.